# Single iOS Storyboard vs. Separate iPhone/iPad Storyboards for 3-Pane Layout

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a Mac app with 3 vertical panes (A, B, and C) and it's easy to set them up with an `NSSplitViewController`. 
[image: Mac App]
But as I attempt to build the iOS version of the app, it seems to get a bit more complicated.

This is what I'm hoping to achieve:

[image: App Layout]

**What I Know So Far:** I can use a **single** iOS storyboard for all this with a slide-out menu and a `UISplitViewController`, but I won't get the 3-pane iPad landscape layout (which is pretty important to me).

**Here's my question:** Will I have to do this as **two separate storyboards**--one for iPad with a `UISplitViewController` and one for iPhone with a slide-out menu? Is there any way to get all I want in a single storyboard without being a `Level 89 UIKit Engineer`?

I'm using Xcode 11 (beta) and Swift 5. I intend to support iOS 12+. Thank you!